# Windows7: ei.cfg removal tool not working completely

Tags: windows-7

I needed to remove ei.cfg since I will be using my windows 7 pro key.

steps I used:

1. ran the tool against the Windows 7 Ultimate iso
2. uncompress the ISO into a folder in the HDD. I cannot see traces of ei.cfg in the sources folder. I used Explorer and command prompt for the presence of the file.
3. Created a USB installer using rufus and Windows7 USB/DVD download tool and the ei.cfg is present.

I know it's easy to remove just ei.cfg once I created the USB installer but perhaps I'm doing it wrong? Thanks

Comment: Just download the appropriate [ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7)? Since you seem to be able to remove ei.cfg where is the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to extract the ISO, delete the file, then create the ISO?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062) is a better download link for OEM users because the other link supplied only works for retail licenses